# Trains between Riga and Tartu

Tags: trains, estonia, latvia, riga

On Tartu's [wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tartu) page it states

> Direct trains between Tartu and Riga are scheduled to resume after the completion of track construction.

I will be in Riga in 2 weeks and I was hoping to visit Tartu for a day trip. Since wikitravel is not always up to date, I was hoping someone here has any info about the train line Riga - Tartu. When will it be operational? (Or is it already?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plan to get the higher speed train between Riga and Tartu [Russian](http://xn--80aaebb0agfy5e0g.xn--p1ai/index.php?id=147).  Currently though there is a way to use the train to get from Riga to Tartu but it involves 2 different legs: [Riga -> Valga and Valga -> Tartu](http://www.meganstarr.com/2014/11/getting-tartu-estonia-riga-latvia.html).  And from what I can see it's a lot slower then a bus.

Comment: Both links are dead.